# How to add no of days to current time?

Tags: apache-pig

this is my requirement

```
A = Load 'number' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,name:chararray,join_date:chararray)
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (join_date is NULL ?AddDuration(CurrentTime(),1000):join_date);
dump b;
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: The second argument to AddDuration is Duration String, passing a duration string instead of 1000 will help. Check answer for a snippet.

Answer (score 3):

As per API : AddDuration(datetime, duration); datetime : A datetime object. duration : The duration string in ISO 8601 format.

We have to pass a duration string in ISO 8601 format as the second argument.

Ref :

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#add-duration
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

For the use case shared in question:

**Input : Note that the first value in date field is null or empty**

```
()
(20150625)
```

**Pig Script :**

```
date_test = LOAD '/Users/muralirao/learning/pig/a.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (join_date:chararray);
default_date_plus_2_days = FOREACH date_test GENERATE ((join_date IS NULL) ? AddDuration(CurrentTime(),'P2D') : ToDate(join_date,'yyyyMMdd')) AS join_date;
display = FOREACH default_date_plus_2_days GENERATE ToString(join_date,'yyyyMMdd') as display_date;
DUMP display;
```

N.B : The second argument to AddDuration here is 'P2D' i.e. 2 Days. Check ISO_8601 standard of representing Duration object.

**Output : DUMP display**

```
(20150627)
(20150625)
```